Representation for real part of a holomorphic function on the circle
Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the closed unit disk $\{z: |z|\leq 1\}$, with $u$ its real part and $v$ its imaginary part, i.e. $f = u + i v$.
Suppose $u$ fulfills that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} u(1, \theta)\mathrm{d}\theta = 0,
$$
where $u(r, \theta)$ is the polar coordinate form of $u$. Show the following holds:
$$
u(1,\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \text{p.v.} \int_0^{2\pi}\cot \frac{\varphi-\theta}
{2} v(1,\varphi)\mathrm{d}\varphi,$$
where $\text{p.v.}$ stands for the Cauchy principal value.

My attempts: Fix $r=1$ in $u(r,\theta)=u(1,\theta):=u(\theta)$, so that $u(\theta)$ is a function on the cirle. Then we wirte $u$ in its Fourier series, and get
$$
u(\theta) = \sum\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{in\theta}  \int_0^{2\pi} u(\varphi) e^{-in\varphi}\mathrm{d}\varphi = \lim_N S_N(\theta) = \lim_N (D_N*u)(\theta),
$$
where $D_N$ is the Dirichelet kernel:
\begin{aligned}
D_N(\varphi-\theta) = \sum_{|n|\leq N}e^{in(\varphi-\theta)} &= \frac{\sin(N+1/2)(\varphi-\theta)}{\sin(1/2(\varphi-\theta))} \\
&= \sin N(\varphi-\theta)\cot\frac{\varphi-\theta}{2}+\cos N(\varphi-\theta).
\end{aligned}
Then we can write $u$ with
$$
u(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}u(\varphi)\cot\frac{\varphi-\theta}{2}\sin N(\varphi-\theta)d\varphi+\int_0^{2\pi}u(\varphi)\cos N(\varphi-\theta)d\varphi\right).
$$
The second term in the above should tend to $0$ as $N\to \infty$, due to the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, and the first term, which is left, looks alike the desired formula to be proved. But then I dont know how to proceed and how to work with the condition $\int_0^{2\pi} u(1, \theta)\mathrm{d}\theta = 0$.
Thanks in advance!

I think I now have a solution.
Consider the Fourier series expansion of $f$ on the unit circle, we have
$$
f = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{f}_j e^{ij\theta} = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\hat{f}_j e^{ij\theta},
$$
where $\hat{f}_j = 0$ for $j<0$ (a straightforward calculation would verify this), which just conincide with the series expansion for $f$ as a holomolphic function. On the other hand, writing the expansion in its real part and imaginaty part respectively, we get
$$
f = \sum_j (\hat{u}_j+i \hat{v}_j)e^{ij\theta}.
$$
We thus must have
$$
\hat{u}_j = -i\hat{v}_j, \quad \text{for all } j<0,
$$
and taking the conjugate of the above will yeild
$$
\hat{u}_j = i\hat{v}_j, \quad \text{for all } j>0.
$$
Since $\int_0^{2\pi} u \mathrm{d}\theta=0$, we have $\hat{u}_0 = 0$ and consequently
\begin{aligned}
u(\theta) &= \sum_{j\neq 0}\hat{u}_j e^{ij\theta} \\
&= i\sum_{j>0} \hat{v}_je^{ij\theta} - i\sum_{j<0}\hat{v}_{j}e^{ij\theta}\\
&= \lim_N \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}v(\varphi)i\left(\sum_{j>0}e^{-ij(\theta-\varphi)} -\sum_{j<0}e^{-ij(\theta-\varphi)}\right)\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=\lim_N \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}v(\varphi) \left(\cot\frac{\varphi-\theta}{2}-\frac{\cos(N+1/2)(\varphi-\theta)}{\sin (\varphi-\theta)/2}\right)\mathrm{d}\varphi.
\end{aligned}
The second term in the integral should go to $0$ when $N\to\infty$, by considering its Cauchy principal value and using Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. Then we are left with
$$
u(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\text{p.v.}\int_0^{2\pi}v(\varphi) \cot\frac{\varphi-\theta}{2}\mathrm{d}\varphi.
$$
